# query to segregate users based on role per project in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains projectID, UserID and RoleID along with other columns.

I trying to get a query that will give me the users based on role for each project.

I tried if and case statements but was able to address this.

table:

```
projectid   | userid | roleid | flag 
1000001     | 20001  | 1      | Y    
1000001     | 20002  | 2      | Y    
1000001     | 20003  | 2      | Y   
1000001     | 20004  | 3      | Y    
1000001     | 20005  | 1      | Y   
1000002     | 20006  | 3      | Y
```

consider role 1 = junior, 2 = TL, 3 = HOD, I'm trying to get something like this

```
projectid | junior       | TL           | HOD 
1000001   | 20001, 20005 | 20002, 20003 | 20004
1000002   | -------------| -------------| 20006
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? You cannot be using both at the same time.

Comment: @KP: SQL Server is the name of a Microsoft-product and not the generic term of sql database management systems. MySQL and SQL Server are DBMS, but MySQL is not a SQL Server, do you understand the difference?
In addition, there's a sql standard, but every dbms has his own enhancements. So it's important to tell us exactly which dbms you want to use.

Comment: For ***[SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4be58/4)*** try the query given in link

Comment: @omeinusch: The application I'm dealing with talks to multiple backends which includes mysql and sql-server, atleast in this case the two database have similar content from different entities (how? merger and acquisitions) and at runtime we decide which one to talk to. Hope this clarifies your concern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [**group_concat**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select projectid,
group_concat(case when roleid = 1 then userid end) junior,
group_concat(case when roleid = 2 then userid end) senior,
group_concat(case when roleid = 3 then userid end) TL
from table1
group by projectid
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba35b/7)